# How to Search a Database of Package Deals for Specific Items with the Fewest Unwanted Extra Items

Tags: optimization

**Short Description**

I have a database of special offers that bundle several items together.  I want to be able to search for a list of specific items and get a combination of bundles that includes all those items with the fewest unwanted extras.

**Example**

My database has bundles like these:

```
Bundle 1: Item A X2, Item B X1, Item D X4
Bundle 2: Item A X5, Item C X1, Item E X3
Bundle 3: Item B X2, Item C X3, Item D X3
Bundle 4: Item C X10, Item D X1, Item F X4
```

I want 10 of Item A, 4 of Item C, and 1 of Item E.  I want to search for a combination of bundles that yields the items I want with the fewest extra items.  The items I want can vary and should be easily editable in the search.

Comment: Can you give an example of the schema with CREATE statements?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: The honest truth is that I am looking at the idea in general, rather than for a specific architecture or DBMS.  Currently I'm just using .csv files to build a dictionary of the data an manipulate that, looking at moving to sqlite.  The point of the question, though, is more about the idea, the algorithm, the thought process (rather than a specific piece of code for a specific build.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anyone has come up with a complete answer for your question. This sounds like a complex math question which does not belong on the "Database Administrators" site.

With that said, Joe Celko has an article that might help you. [Bin Packing Problems: The SQL](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/bin-packing-problems-the-sql/)